# Mathematica doesn't simplify a simple expression

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

The question is simple as that. I have:

```
$Assumptions[v \[Element] Reals]
x[u_, v_] := {f[u], g[u] Cos[v], g[u] Sin[v]}
pil[{x_, y_, z_}, {a_, b_, c_}] := x*a + y*b - z*c
pil[D[x[u, v], u], D[x[u, v], v]]
-2 Cos[v] g[u] Sin[v] Derivative[1][g][u]
```

and for some reason, `Simplify` won't turn the last expression into `-Sin[2v] Derivative[1][g][u]`. I looked a bit around before asking, so I also tried `FullSimplify` and `$Assumptions[v \[Element] Reals]`, to no avail. Why is all of this going wrong? Can someone explain to me, please? (I find a bit hard to trust a program that can't use the simple fact that $\sin(2v) = 2 \sin v \cos v$.)

Comment: Try using `TrigReduce`

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much! Anyway, I'll leave the question here, in case someone shows up to give a more technical explanation for the problem.

Comment: The reason is *Mathematica* is such a large system with a lot of rewrite rules and special cases of those rules. So sometimes you'll have to use available special functions to force it to do certain simplifications as in this case.

Comment: That makes it clearer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `TrigReduce` to do what you want:

```
TrigReduce[-2 Cos[v] g[u] Sin[v] Derivative[1][g][u]]
```

> ```
> -g[u] Sin[2 v] Derivative[1][g][u]
> ```